# Regular expression that match string format "1,22,3,44"

Tags: php, regex

I tried:

```
preg_match("/((\d)+,?)+/",$string)
```

it returns correct result for:

> 1,2,3,4,5

but it also matches with:

> 1,2a
>
> 1aaaa
>
> 1,2,3,

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you want to match `1,22,3,44` or `1,2,3,4`? Are you just trying to match numbers that are comma separated?

Comment: I just trying to match numbers that are comma separated and not ends with comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
preg_match('~^(?:\d+(?:,(?!$)|$))+$~', $string);
```

Comment: That's one monstrous regex for something so simple.

Comment: This is work.. but I not sure what is '~' ... I gonna learn more.. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @CatInTheShell It's just the delimiter saying the start and end of the regular expression. You can use virtually anything there as long as you use the same character to end the expression.

Comment: I know it doesn't @CasimiretHippolyte. He said he wanted it to capture strings too though below. Of course, he DIDN'T say that in his question.

Comment: String type, but only numbers and comma. Sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
^\d+(,\d+)*$
```

The first `^\d+` matches for the beginning of the string and a number. Then you optionally match for a comma followed by a number (and that groups can be present 0 or multiples times). Finally the `$` match for the end of string. To make sure there are nothing left after the last number.

Here is a state machine showing how the expression works :

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/cFu6uLgoLLzU_LFT)

This can match for example : `8`, `1,2,4`.
But wont match : `8,`, `,2` or `1,2a`

Comment: Sorry not putting it back in the php cpde but writing for a cell phone is hard enough!

Comment: I forgot to mention that string also valid even single number

Comment: I still think this is a better answer. Easily modifiable to accept alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @CatInTheShell This do accept a single number. The group `,\d+` is optional. So it would accept a single number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the anchors `^` and `$` to prevent other matches:

```
preg_match("/^((\d)+,?)+$/",$string)
             ^          ^
```

Although... your expression might be better like this:

```
preg_match("/^\d+(,\d+)*$/",$string)
```

What is happening with `((\d)+,?)+` is that it matches the first few characters it finds and once it is done, it says it matched.

The anchors `^` and `$` mean the beginning of the string and the end of the string respectively, meaning that the beginning must match until the end.

Comment: `1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,`